# AngularJS simple app webpage stops rendering code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to go through an AngularJS tutorial on codeschool.com but as I work through it and refresh my browser to see my progress, at some point in the tutorial the browser always ends up loading a blank webpage and won't load the code anymore. I've attempted the tutorial from the start twice and it happened both times at different points.

I must keep doing something wrong in my code. Has anyone else had this issue or know how to fix it?

I've seen a couple similar questions on here but the answers haven't worked.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='store'>
<head>
<html lang="en-US">
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
      <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
      <h2> {{store.product.price}} </h2>
      <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
      <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the JS file:

```
(function (){
  const app = angular.module('store', [ ]);

  app.controller("StoreController", function(){
    this.product = gems;
  });

  const gems = [
    {
      name: "Dodecahedron",
      price: 2.95,
      description: 'Many sided gem. Would look great in a ring.',
    },
    {
      name: "Pentagonal Gem",
      price: 5.95,
      description: 'A gem shaped like a pentagon. More expensive and 
more shiny',
    }
  ];

})();
```

Comment: Why still use the old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: you have a mismatched variable name between your controller and your view and then inside your `ng-repeat` you are including your controller alias instead of accessing each of the repeated elements directly.

First change `this.product = gems;` in your controller to `this.products = gems;` and then change your `ng-repeat` div to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
  <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
  <h2> {{product.price}} </h2>
  <p> {{product.description}} </p>
  <button>Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```